# Root for HTC ONE M7?

Tags: rooting, htc

Is there any way to root the HTC M7 and flash CM without loosing any data? My friend has recently rooted his phone,  a M7 too,  and lost all his data.  Any way to prevent this?  Links will be appreciated :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can root without losing data by installing TWRP and installing SuperSU.

If you want to flash CM you will then have to wipe all data to install that.